# Will Zend let me connect to multiple legacy databases for a single page?

Tags: zend-framework

I have to connect to lots of legacy databases and bring back the information for a single integrated page.

Will Zend let me do that "naturally" or is that something that can be done in Zend only as a "hack"?

Am I better off rolling my own for things like this kind of project and leaving frameworks out of the picture?

Thanks.

edit:  most frameworks don't seem to cater to this.  I often feel like I'm the only guy that needs to connect to a boatload of resources and put them in one page.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limitation on Zend to do that, you can use the database resource loader to load several instances of Zend_Db objects and use them at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any problems.  There's even a "multidb" resource plugin: [Zend_Application_Resource_Multidb](http://zendframework.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.multidb) which sounds like it supports exactly your use-case.